# Can't sync android project gradle kts with huawei

Tags: android, gradle, android-jetpack-compose, huawei-mobile-services, huawei-developers

I have this in the project gradle kts

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
plugins {
    id("com.android.application") version "8.2.0" apply false
    id ("com.android.library") version "8.2.0" apply false
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.android") version "1.8.10" apply false
    id ("com.huawei.agconnect:agcp") version "1.6.3.300" apply false

}
```

and this in the app module gradle kts

```
plugins {
    id("com.android.application")
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.android")
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt")
//    id("com.google.gms.google-services")
//    id("com.google.firebase.crashlytics")
    id("com.huawei.agconnect")
}
```

When  i click sync it gives me this error

> org.gradle.api.plugins.UnknownPluginException: Plugin [id: 'com.huawei.agconnect'] was not found in any of the following sources:

and sometimes with

> plugin id 'com.huawei.agconnect:agcp' is invalid: Plugin id contains invalid char ':' (only

Comment: Any help please to how use gradle kts with huawei connect is greatly appreciated